# LibreOffice doesn't display images

Tags: 11.10, libreoffice

My LibreOffice is not showing images. They look like this:

[image: "Object21" instead of image]

Can someone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe displaying images is disabled? This is possible and very useful to speed up working with large documents holding a lot of images. Check Menu **Tools > Options > LibreOffice Writer > View**:

[image: view menu]

Make sure *Graphics and Objects* isn't disabled.