# Blank images on copy paste from pdf to image editor or LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice, pdf, image-processing

Lately I have to extract few specific images from `.pdf` files and save them as image file. For example, the following is the image copied from a PDF (right click and copy image using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).

[image: two graphs]

When I paste the same either in LibreOffice Writer or an image editor like KolourPaint, I end up with a blank image something like this. Can anyone suggest how I can work around this issue?

[image: blank image space]

Comment: Which pdf-viewer to you use? Is the pdf freely available in the internet? If so, please post a link.

Comment: First of all check that `Graphics and Objects` is enabled, as mentioned here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/112681

Comment: @cmks: I use `adobe` and I tried different pdf viewers also. I tried pasting in different destinations like `kolourpaint`. Still its blank

Comment: @whtyger: Tried it already and not working yet. See above comment also

Comment: So images are replaced with placeholders when you paste them from the clipboard? What happens if you paste an image using **Insert -> Image -> From File**?

Comment: does copying (small) pictures out of freely available pdf-files work? Try the logo on first side of this one: http://www.amstat.org/publications/jse/v18n2/cooper.pdf

Comment: What happens if you do a printscreen in ubuntu, copy it to the clipboard and paste it to libreoffice?

Comment: @cmks Printscreen and pasting to libreoffice and kolourpaint are working fine. Only issue is copying images from pdf doesnt work.

Comment: This occurs with every PDF or only with some of them? Can you provide the link to some affected PDF?

Comment: I have a hack, its not pretty.  You could use a key binding, or panel app to call the command, `mate-screenshot -a` (or gnome-screenshot , or some other similar program) select the image area you want,  then put the file into a document.

Comment: again: does copying (small) pictures out of freely available pdf-files work? Try the logo on first side of this one: http://amstat.org/publications/jse/v18n2/cooper.pdf

Comment: It is an outside chance but as what you are describing is not normal behaviour for libreoffice at least. You could try resetting your configuration to defaults. Close all libreoffice windows and then run `mv -v $HOME/.config/libreoffice/4/user $HOME/.config/libreoffice/4/user_bak` and then when you restart the defaults will be in use...

Comment: @cmks : I tried the top left logo on the pdf you shared. On both `libreOffice Writer` and `Kolourpaint`, they appear blank.

Comment: @SathishKrishnan Found this thread: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/why-doesn%27t-copy-image-work-in-adobe-acrobat-reader-762271/ . If it looks promising, then check [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/150100) post. You can find `pdfimages` tool in `poppler-utils` package.